# error: expected primary-expression before ')' token (C)

Tags: c++, c, function, struct, compiler-errors

I am trying to call a function named `characterSelection(SDL_Surface *screen, struct SelectionneNonSelectionne sel)` which returns a `void`

This is the `.h` of the function I try to call:

```
struct SelectionneNonSelectionne;
void characterSelection(SDL_Surface *screen, struct SelectionneNonSelectionne);
void resetSelection(SDL_Surface *screen, struct SelectionneNonSelectionne);
```

On my main function, I try to call it like this:

```
characterSelection(screen, SelectionneNonSelectionne);
```

When I compile, I have the message:

```
 error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
```

I made the `includes`. I suppose I miscall the second argument, my `struct`. But, I can't find why on the net.

Have you got any idea about what I did wrong?

Comment: You need to pass objects to the function. You seem to be trying to pass a type (`SelectionneNonSelectionne`.)

Comment: I have tried to remove the argument 'SelectionneNonSelectionne',  I obviously have the error message too few arguments, like this: `error: too few arguments to function "void characterSelection(SDL_Surface*, SelectionneNonSelectionne)"` What can I do If I must call something I can't call?

Comment: When did passing an object become remove a parameter?

Comment: just a missunderstanding by myself, I'm a beginner..

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should create a variable of the type SelectionneNonSelectionne.

```
struct SelectionneNonSelectionne var;
```

After that pass that variable to the function like

```
characterSelection(screen, var);
```

The error is caused since you are passing the type name SelectionneNonSelectionne

Answer (score 5):

A function call needs to be performed with objects. You are doing the equivalent of this:

```
// function declaration/definition
void foo(int) {}

// function call
foo(int); // wat!??
```

i.e. passing a type where an object is required. This makes no sense in C or C++. You need to be doing

```
int i = 42;
foo(i);
```

or

```
foo(42);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're passing a type as an argument, not an object. You need to do `characterSelection(screen, test);` where test is of type `SelectionneNonSelectionne`.

Comment: I'll try to applicate this to my code, I'm very unfamiliar with C. Thanks

Comment: @Flo This is exactly what I told you in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I seen this problem with the latest nightly build of Code::Blocks.  When I switched back to the stable release of Code::Blocks, 20.03 at the time of this writing, the problem went away and my code compiled and ran without problems.  I'm not sure what Code::Blocks is doing, but it is very annoying.  I got this repeatedly on a C++ project for every `NULL` in my code, forcing me to use `nullptr` instead.